# How to simplify Sigma notation with variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I have following Sigma notations:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{9} x_i$$

$\ x_i $ is equal 4.

And the second Sigma notation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{9} x_iy_i$$

$\ x_i $ is equal 4 and $\ y_i $ is 3.

**Update**

The task is defined as following:

[image]

[image]

How to solve the task?

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: @projectilemotion Thanks for the hint, I just corrected it.

Comment: It appears as though you are asking how to simplify the summations.  Note the following things: Firstly, what sigma notation represents in the first place: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i = x_1+x_2+x_3+\dots+x_n$.  [Read about it on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation).  Next, note that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 1 = \underbrace{1+1+\dots+1}_{n~\text{terms}}=n$

Comment: So... for your example $\sum\limits_{i=1}^9x_i = x_1+x_2+\dots+x_9$.  You say for the first problem that $x_i=4$, presumably for each $i$... so if you replace each $x_i$ with $4$ in the above you get...

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: Do we have to sum the values for you ?

Comment: Please show me, how to solve it.

Comment: @zwin What am I doing wrong? That is my homework and do not know how to solve it.

Comment: "*What am I doing wrong?*"  We don't know what you are doing wrong because we don't know what you are doing.  You haven't shown us any work or effort, and so we haven't had the opportunity to see any mistakes, which in and of itself can be considered a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not solve your exact problem, because even minor hints will essentially do it for you leaving no work for you to do yourself.  Instead I will construct a similar problem and show that one.

$\begin{array}{c|cccc} i&1&2&3&4\\\hline x_i&2&0&2&3\\\hline y_i&1&3&0&1\end{array}$

The summation $\sum\limits_{i=1}^4 x_i$ represents *by definition*

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^4 x_i=x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4$

We may now replace the values with what they are equal to.  For example, replacing $x_1$, we look at the table for the row corresponding to the $x$'s and the column corresponding to $i=1$ to see:

$\begin{array}{c|cccc} i&\color{red}{1}&2&3&4\\\hline \color{red}{x_i}&\color{red}{2}&0&2&3\\\hline y_i&1&3&0&1\end{array}$

We learn then that $x_1=2$ meaning we have

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^4 x_i=\color{red}{x_1}+x_2+x_3+x_4=\color{red}{2}+x_2+x_3+x_4$

Similarly, we can replace the rest to see $\sum\limits_{i=1}^4 x_i=x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=2+0+2+3=7$

---

In a very similar fashion $\sum\limits_{i=1}^4 (x_iy_i)= x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3+x_4y_4=2\cdot1+0\cdot 3+2\cdot 0+3\cdot 1=5$

Your problem is just asking that you learn and understand the meaning of [$\Sigma$-summation notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation).  After the definition is learned, all that is left for you to specifically do here is read the table and perform the necessary arithmetic.

Comment: Your comment is highly appreciated, I got the way it works! Thanks to your hints, now I can solve my problems.

Answer (score 1):

To help illustrate what the sums mean, I have written C code that computes them. Things to note are that each term of the sum uses a different value of $x_i$ or $y_i$ (written `x[i]` and `y[i]` in the code),
and the terms include with $i$ equal to the number underneath the $\sum$ sign as well as $i$ equal to the number above $\sum$; they also include all integer values of $i$ in between.

```
compute_sums()
{
  // An extra element is inserted at the front of the arrays because
  // C starts its numbering at zero but the data were numbered from 1 up.
  //        i:  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
  int x[10] = { 0,  4,  7,  2,  0,  9,  2,  5, 12,  1 };
  int y[10] = { 0,  3,  0,  5,  6,  3, 11,  1,  5,  4 };
  int a, b, c, i;

  a = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= 9; ++i)
  {
    a = a + x[i];
  }
  // Now  a  is the desired sum for part (a)

  b = 0;
  for (i = 3; i <= 8; ++i)
  {
    b = b + y[i];
  }
  // Now  b  is the desired sum for part (b)

  c = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= 9; ++i)
  {
    c = c + (x[i] * y[i]);
  }
  // Now  c  is the desired sum for part (c)

  printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
}
```